# Figure out the key strength of AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I am trying to figure out the encryption and the key strength used in a application, All that i have access is to the application debug logs. While going through the logs I observed the following items:

- provider=BC
- algorithm=AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING

I could conclude from the above observations that AES is being used, but could not figure out the key strength. After a few RnD here and there i came to the below conclusion.

Does AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING being in use mean that the key length is 128 bit? Can someone tell me whether this is correct?

Comment: The first list item is **provider=BC**

Comment: what does it have to do with Java?

Comment: No related to java. It more suited to be asked on [security community](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Since BC stood for Bouncy Castle, which is a set of encryption libraries used in JAVA as per my research and hence, tagged JAVA.

Comment: FYI if you are concerned with strength of actual **security**, AES key size is irrelevant; all AES key sizes are secure, but ECB is insecure in most applications, and bad key management can easily reduce your security to only 60 bits or 40 or even none at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING being in use mean that the key length is 128 bit?Can someone tell me whether this is correct?

No, it doesn't tell you the used key. AES supports key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bit. All JCE providers for Java that I know use the appropriate algorithm (AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256) depending on the size of the key that you pass in. If you cannot figure out how big the byte array is that is passed into the Cipher as a key, then chances are slim to determine the strength.

If you have access to the machine it is running on, then you can check whether Unlimited Strength policy files ([example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) for Java 7) are installed, which are necessary for 256 bit (and 192 bit?). If they are not installed, then the key will most likely be 128 bit wide.

Comment: Hi, Artjob, 
Thanks for the responses. It was really helpful. I reviewed the logs again and icould find a line item which says "Unlimited strength JCE installed". Can i conclude from this that 256 bit is in use.

Comment: No, you can only conclude that AES-256 is possible. That doesn't mean that AES-256 is actually used which depends on the code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Artjom.!!